# Model isn't updatd on AJAX submit link invocation

Tags: ajax, wicket

I'm trying to implement an AJAXfied Wicket list view. On my research I stumbled upon the code on [this site](http://www.oktech.hu/kb/adding-and-removing-rows-wicket-listview-via-ajax) and modified it a bit.

The model is not updated properly. So whenever a value is entered in a text field, it is forgotten if the AJAX submit link is invoked (the text field is empty). Why does this happen? I don't see any issue with this code. Wicket version is 1.5.2.

Here is the Java code:

```
// Initialization of form
...

// List all rows
ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>(2);
rows.add(new String());
rows.add(new String());

final ListView<String> lv = new ListView<String>("rows", rows) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
        int index = item.getIndex() + 1;
        item.add(new Label("index", index + "."));

        TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>("text", item.getModel());
        item.add(text);
    }
};
rowPanel.add(lv);

    AjaxSubmitLink addLink = new AjaxSubmitLink("addRow", form) {

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        if (target != null) target.add(rowPanel);       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        lv.getModelObject().add(new String());
        if (target != null) target.add(rowPanel);
    }
};
addLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
rowPanel.add(addLink);
...
```

And here is the mark up:

```
<div wicket:id="rowPanel">
    <span wicket:id="rows">
        <span wicket:id="index">1.</span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="text"/>
    </span>
    <a href="#" wicket:id="addRow">Add row</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you to call the setReuseItems(true) on the List. Also, you can have a look at the example here: http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/

Comment: @bert Please, repost your comment as an answer. This is exceedingly likely to be the right answer, and is also pointing the OP to the right direction with the link. I will if you don't! :-)

Comment: @Xavi López: thanks, will do. Glad i beat you to an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous comment as anwser:

You may need to call setReuseItems(true) on the listview.

Another way of ajaxifying a listview can be found at [the Wicket in Action blog](http://wicketinaction.com/2008/10/repainting-only-newly-created-repeater-items-via-ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Your example would work fine if you hadn't added the following line:

```
addLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
```

Your link doesnt process the form like he would normally do (update models etc, see [IFormSubmitter](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/IFormSubmitter.html#getDefaultFormProcessing%28%29))

You could use nested Forms to updated only the area you need and set defaultFormProcessing back to true.

Like:

```
    <form wicket:id="form">
(...) <!-- (other form elements you dont want to get updated -->
    <form wicket:id="repeaterForm"> <!-- form for your repeater textfields-->
        <div wicket:id="refreshDiv">
            <input type="textfield" wicket:id="repeaterText" />
        </div>
        <a wicket:id="addMoreLink>add more</a>
    </form>
</form>
```

Wicket will make sure you don't actually have nested forms within your markup (it will replace the nested form with a div) because it ain't valid HTML. But it would work as if the forms are nested nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the model from the target like this:

```
IModel model = target.getModel();
```

Then cast to the listView. I don't know if this works, but I have some similar code here.